# Remote logging not logging, stuck after Waiting to accept a new client

Tags: java, log4j, syslog

I want to log to a remote system. Below is my configuration

**log4j.properties file contents**

```
  log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server
  log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
  log4j.appender.server.Port=4712
  log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=<RemoteHost>
  log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

**log4j-server.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] [%m]%n
```

**Command I am using is**

```
java -classpath log4j-1.2.15.jar org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 log4j.properties
```

but my log file has only the below contents; I  don't see logs getting appended to the file. I am not sure what I missed here.

> [2018-09-19 18:42:07,962] [main] [Listening on port 4712]
>
> [2018-09-19 18:42:07,978] [main] [Waiting to accept a new client.]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your command should read like this instead:

`java -classpath log4j-1.2.15.jar org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 log4j-server.properties`.

This command line is supposed to start your Log4j server - which is the `RemoteHost` in your setup. So the command line should have the server properties file as an argument, instead of the logging properties file.